# Koa - Async function within Async function error handling

Tags: javascript, node.js, error-handling, async-await, koa

In my `app.js` I have the following...

```
app.use(async (ctx, next) => {
  try {
    await next()
  } catch (err) {
    ctx.status = 400
    ctx.body = `Uh-oh: ${err.message}`
    console.log('Error handler:', err.message)
  }
});

app.use(router());
```

Then in `routes` I have defined...

```
router.post('/', retrieve);
```

The logic for retrieve is structured as so...

```
const retrieve = async ctx => {
  Object.keys(ctx.request.files).forEach((key) => {
    process(files[key]);
  });
};
```

Now let's say I throw an error in `retrieve`...

```
const retrieve = async ctx => {
  throw new Error(`Error!`);
  Object.keys(ctx.request.files).forEach((key) => {
    process(files[key]);
  });
};
```

This will work correctly and bubble up all the way to `app.js`. However, the `process` function is also using `async`, if I throw the error there instead...

```
const retrieve = async ctx => {
  Object.keys(ctx.request.files).forEach((key) => {
    process(files[key]);
  });
};

const process = async (file) => {
  throw new Error(`Error!`);
  ...
```

I get the following error...

> UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Error!

Why am I getting `UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning`? How can I fix it and make it so that any error thrown inside of `process` gets bubbled up to `app.js`?

Comment: why is `ctx` async? of course there's an unhandled rejections ... `process` throws, and there's nothing catching it

Comment: @JaromandaX I tried wrapping `process` in a try/catch but same error

Comment: Hope this help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37576685/using-async-await-with-a-foreach-loop/37576787#37576787

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the forEach loop is not async, the errors get thrown after it's execution and are therefore not able to bubble up to app.js. Now there are two solutions to it, either you can use a `for` loop, or map the promises and wait for all of them to resolve. Sample code according to your problem :

1. For calling `process` sequentially

```
const retrieve = async ctx => {
    const ctxKeys = Object.keys(ctx.request.files);
    for(let i = 0 ; i < ctxKeys.length ;++i){
        await process(files[ctxKeys[i]]);
    }
};
```

2. For calling `process` asynchronously

```
const retrieve = async ctx => {
   await Promise.all(Object.keys(ctx.request.files).map(async (key) => {
     await process(files[key]);
   }));
};
```